# Get Bounding Box for ALL Bodies

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, 2d, physics, box2d

I am trying to get the bounding box for all the bodies in a box2d world (think a scenario where I want to get the largest y-value of all bodies).

I need to do this every frame so am not looking to iterator over the bounding box of every body. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If the objects can move arbitrarily, then iterating over all bounding boxes is exactly what you'll have to do. Can you put some restrictions on how the objects can move?

Comment: I can't do any axial restrictions or anything. It's a basic scene with a flat ground and ~20-70 dynamic bodies. I was hoping that box2d was maintaining some geometric data structure which might contain this information.

Comment: I know nothing about box2d. What about velocity? If you can establish bounds on that, then you can say, e.g. "there's no way this object can leave the bounding box within the next 10 cycles, so we can ignore it until then".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up just iterating over the all bodies.